# 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I am using Secure Gateway of ibm blue-mix.
However, I do not know how to do "500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection" error.

The situation is as follows:
When accessing, the following message will be displayed on the Secure Gateway client.
    [INFO] (Client ID keqdVTJMrJt_prF) Connection #1 is being estabrished to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:nnn
The display of the log is
 "[INFO ] SRVE0242I: [ChisInq003] [/ChisInq003] [Servlet.ChisServlet003]: Initialization successful.".
However, if it takes about two minutes, "500 Error" will be displayed.

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

If the connection fails after ~2 minutes, it sounds like the connection between the Secure Gateway Client and the host:port it is trying to connect to is timing out which implies a network issue.

Are there any additional Secure Gateway Client logs that can be shared that might contain an error? What is it that you're trying to connect to via Secure Gateway?

Comment: I am trying to connect to DB2 on host at Secure Gateway.
Log is as follows.
[2017-11-08 09:56:09.299] [[33mWARN[39m] (Client ID 7476) The ACL file provided during startup will not be imported until a connection has been established to your gateway.
[2017-11-08 09:56:10.429] [[31mERROR[39m] (Client ID 7476) The Secure Gateway gateway ID was either not recognized or requires a security token to connect, error was: 401
cli> [2017-11-08 09:56:10.429] [[32mINFO[39m] (Client ID 7476) Process exiting without errors due to user or server request

Comment: The gateway ID and security token are confirmed to be the same as securegw_service.config.

Comment: Having the SG Client fail to connect to the SG Server is a very different issue than having the connection to the DB2 failing.  The logs provided in your initial post shows that your client connected to the SG Server without issue, but that the error encountered was after attempting to connect to the DB2 via SG. Logs surrounding that connection will be helpful.

Comment: So, where should I check?

Comment: Any logs around the `Connection #1 is being established to` would help to identify if that particular connection opened/closed successfully or if it encountered an error.  I would also suggest attempting to telnet the host:port the client is trying to connect to to confirm that the machine hosting the SG Client has the appropriate network access for establishing the connection.